# Will Android kill a background service just after startup?

Tags: android, android-service, foreground-service

I have an Android service which connects to a Bluetooth peripheral.

I don’t want Android to kill my service at its own discretion, as that would defeat the purpose of the app.

However, the app sometimes attempts to launch the service and connect when it just *suspects* the BT device might be in range—which may succeed or not. Unless the connection is successful, I don’t want to bother users with the notification which would be shown when the service becomes a foreground service. (The user can enable or disable this feature, thus it’s not about doing things behind the user’s back.)

I therefore considered delaying the call to `startForeground()` until the Bluetooth connection is complete. Brief description in prose (as code would be lengthy):

- `MyService#onStartCommand()` creates an AsyncTask and launches it (it will run in a background thread, to keep the lengthy Bluetooth connection setup off the UI thread).
- `AsyncTask#run()` sets up the Bluetooth connection.
- `AsyncTask#onPostExecute()` (which runs on the UI thread after `run()` finishes) verifies we’re connected, and if so, calls `startForeground()`, creating the notification.

However, after `onStartCommand()` returns there is a short timeframe in which the service is still a background service.

Is there any risk of Android killing my service in that brief time to reclaim memory (when it would leave a foreground service alone)?

If so, does Android take the time elapsed since the service was started into account (killing the longest-running services first)?

Comment: What is the trigger mechanism for this service to be started? Is the user tapping on something in the UI? BTW, why are you using `AsyncTask` from a service, rather than a plain thread?

Comment: @CommonsWare There are multiple triggers: the user can explicitly tap on something in the UI, or the service can be started through a broadcast receiver (e.g. whenever the device is plugged into a charger). Using `AsyncTask` is mostly a habit, but I also rely on the functionality of its `onPostExecute()` method to run certain things on the UI thread when the task completes.

Comment: "but I also rely on the functionality of its onPostExecute() method to run certain things on the UI thread when the task completes" -- there's very little, if anything, that a service should be doing on the main application thread. For example, AFAIK, you can call `startForeground()` from any thread.

Comment: "Is there any risk of Android killing my service in that brief time to reclaim memory (when it would leave a foreground service alone)?" -- *any* risk? Yes, if your UI is not in the foreground. It's *unlikely* that Android will find the need to terminate your process in that window of time, but "unlikely" is not "impossible". "does Android take the time elapsed since the service was started into account" -- I think memory footprint counts more than age, but I do think that age is a criterion.

Comment: @CommonsWare why not make this an answer?

Comment: Because I have not looked at the out-of-memory killer rules recently to know the impacts of age on termination order.